# C++17 Using Class Template Argument Deduction guides on a type that holds a function's return value

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, class-template, template-argument-deduction

I designed a object that takes in a function and its parameters and holds the function's return value inside the object to be retrieved later.

My goal here is to create a deduction guide for this object that'll allow me to omit the return type of the function in the object's constructor.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename Ret> class footure {
  public:
    template <typename Function, typename... Args>
    explicit footure(Function &&fun, Args &&... args) {
        // ...
        value_ = fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // ...
    }

    Ret get() { return value_; }

  private:
    Ret value_;
};

int add(const int a, const int b) { return a + b; }

int main() {
    auto f = footure<int>(add, 2, 3); // Remove <int>
    auto r = f.get();
}
```

I've looked up resources such as [this PR](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1021r0.html) to try and figure this out, but I could not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to look for [`std::invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of).

```
template <typename Function, typename... Args>
explicit footure(Function&&, Args&&...) -> footure<std::invoke_result_t<Function&&, Args&&...>>;
```

Don't forget to add the header `<type_traits>`.

Comment: Just as I was refreshing this page, I acheived similar results in my code by adding `footure(Function &&fun, Args &&... args)->footure<decltype(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>;`

Comment: Would you please edit the accepted answer to include your solution? I cannot replicate it, but I'm curious.

Comment: Just add the line after the end of the footure block (either mine or xskxzr's), remove the `<int>` and it should just work.

Answer (score 1):

The class must know about the `Function` and `Args` at compile time. Only then can you deduce the type of `_value` like so:

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Function, typename... Args> class footure {
  public:

    explicit footure(Function &&fun, Args &&... args) {
        // ...
        value_ = fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // ...
    }

    auto get() { return value_; }


  private:
     typename std::result_of<Function&(Args...)>::type value_;
};

int add(int a, int b) { return a +b; }

int main() {
    auto f = footure(add, 1, 2); // Remove <int>
    auto r = f.get();
}
```